# issue about tf.layers.batch_normalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I have some queations about tf.layers.batch_normalization: here is a part of my code about batch normalization:

```
layer = tf.layers.dense(self.neighbors_placeholder,1500,activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu,kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        layer = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer,training = self.training_placeholder)
        layer=tf.layers.dropout(layer,rate=0.5,training=self.training_placeholder)
```

And update the moving variables in optimizer:

```
optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
    update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
    with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
        self.optimizer = optimizer.minimize(self.cost,global_step=global_step)
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

During training, I set the training==True, and on evaluation results I set it to False:

```
    feed = {self.centers_placeholder:np.vstack(self.train_centers[index:index+self.batch_size]),
                                self.neighbors_placeholder:np.vstack(self.train_neighbors[index:index+self.batch_size]),
                                self.training_placeholder:True}
     index+=self.batch_size
    _,batch_cost = sess.run([self.optimizer,self.cost],feed_dict = feed)

    feed_metric_test = {self.centers_placeholder:np.vstack(self.test_centers),
                                        self.neighbors_placeholder:np.vstack(self.test_neighbors),self.training_placeholder:False}
   metric_test_step = sess.run(self.loss,feed_dict = feed_metric_test)
```

Store the model:

```
self.saver.save(sess,self.store_path+'1.ckpt')
```

And restore the model when inference:

```
   with tf.Session() as sess:
        self.saver.restore(sess,self.store_path+'1.ckpt')
        embeddings = sess.run(self.embedding,feed_dict = {self.neighbors_placeholder : data,self.training_placeholder:False})
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

My question is: 
1: when I save and restore model, making inference, how the batch normalization works? Is that save and restore all of the moving mean and variances?
2: What does the momentum work in tf.layers.batch_normalization?